# Generic return type with Codable returning error Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred even though Xcode correctly shows return type on output

Tags: swift, generics

I have looked at a variety of related questions on here, but none of the answers appear to work for me right now.

For starters, I have the following function set up with a generic return type that must conform to `Decodable`.

```
func readFile<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> T? {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        return try PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self,
                                                from: data) as T
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I have tried a variety of calls against it, but thus far Xcode keeps returning the error code

```
Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
```

After some experimentation, I have arrived at the following:

```
if let file: CodableStruct = readFile(url: url) as? CodableStruct {
    // File is reported as the correct type here
    // but I still get "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
}
```

My goal is to store a variety of different objects that conform to Codable, and then be able to retrieve them with the above function.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the conditional downcast `as? CodableStruct`

```
if let file: CodableStruct = readFile(url: url) {
```

and – not related to the error – remove also the redundant bridge cast `as T`.

---

Consider to make the function `throw`

```
func readFile<T: Decodable>(url: URL) throws -> T {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    return try PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward the errors along. Don't hide them with an optional.

```swift
func readFile<Decodable: Swift.Decodable>(url: URL) throws -> Decodable {
  try PropertyListDecoder().decode(
    Decodable.self,
    from: Data(contentsOf: url)
  )
}
```

```swift
let file: CodableStruct = try readFile(url: url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the compiler was confused by the `try` command in my `readFile` function.

I had to add `( )` to help it understand the statement.

```
return (try PropertyListDecoder().decode(T.self,
                                         from: data)) as T
```

However, vadian was correct in that I could remove the downcast from the call.

To the comments about throwing, I do handle the error, but I cut down the code for purpose of making the question shorter. Thank you for addressing that though!

Comment: `as T` is still redundant because the decoder knows the type.